# DOM XSS detection using javascript(source and sink detection)

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss

We are trying to detect DOM XSS vulnerabilities in the javascript code on the client side using static code analysis by finding the sources and sinks

We are trying to 
We tried to use the JSPrime tool https://github.com/dpnishant/jsprime, but when we run it on our code it is giving maximum stack limit exceeded, is there any other known libraries/tool to detect source and sink in javascript code, or any other way to detect dom xss on the client side

Comment: Have you found any way to solve this problem?